# macro accuracy in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to calculate `macro accuracy`.

if I set

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support
y_true=[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
y_pred=[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2]
        
print(precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred,average='macro'))

   Output: (0.5, 0.4722222222222222, 0.4857142857142857, None)
```

will the output `recall` be equivalent to macro accuracy?

How to calculate maco accuracy by scikitlearn metrics?

Comment: You might want to check your code. It starts with a syntax error( and bad indentation).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you better separate the result parameters:

```
prec, rec, fbeta, supp = precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred,average='macro')
```

Second, accuracy and recall are two different things:

```
Accuracy is (correct predictions)/(all predictions)
Recall is (True positives)/(True positives/False negatives)
```

To calculate accuracy using `sklearn` you need:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print(accuracy_score(y_true, y_pred))
```

Comment: Thanks, my question is how to obtain **macro accuracy**